# htaccess not redirecting to main index.php

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, ubuntu

htaccess will not redirect whatever I type to the `index.php` on my server. But it works perfectly on my local server (wamp).

This is the htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options -MultiViews

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

It's the most basic htaccess ....

If I go to the main url there is no problem and the page loads but if I type something like `/inventaris/index` it gives me a 404 page.

On the same server i have other websites using htaccess. One of them is a wordpress blog with permalinks so mod_rewrite is enabled.

Anyone has an idea why this won't work? My live server is running on Ubuntu.

**Update: Loaded Modules**
core mod_log_config mod_logio prefork http_core mod_so mod_alias mod_auth_basic mod_authn_file mod_authz_default mod_authz_groupfile mod_authz_host mod_authz_user mod_autoindex mod_cgi mod_deflate mod_dir mod_env mod_mime mod_negotiation mod_php5 mod_reqtimeout **mod_rewrite** mod_setenvif mod_status

Comment: for development dont use wamp it has lots of problems ive suffered with it

Comment: @Mr.coder don't tell me about it, I noticed that :D I didn't switch yet because I mainly develop on Mac using MAMP

Comment: Do you have .htaccess inside `/inventaris/` also?

Comment: no. that's not an existing folder. inventaris should forward to the controller inventaris.php and index forwards to the method inside that controller

Comment: Can you use `info.php` instead of `index.php` where content of `info.php` would just be: `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`

Comment: I did. What am I looking for? I see the mod_rewrite module (udpated my question with this info)

Comment: What I am looking for is do you still get 404 for `http://example.com/inventaris/index` URL?

Comment: Verify whether your `.htaccess` is enabled or not, by putting same garbage (random) text on top of your `.htaccess` and see if it generates 500 (internal server) error or not?

Comment: Found the problem. check my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some debugging I found out that the `.htaccess` file wasn't doing anything. Not even a basic forward.

After some googling I update the virtual host setting `AllowOverride None` to `AllowOverride All`. Same thing for the default virtual host (just to be sure). And it seem to work now.

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

Explanation I found: **You need to modify the line containing AllowOverride None to read AllowOverride All. This tells Apache that it's okay to allow .htaccess files to over-ride previous directives.**

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that +FollowSymLinks is set under Options, I would use

```
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^ /index.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

This also helps you to get `PATH_INFO`.

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

IndexIgnore */*
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) index.php/$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Thanks but still the same problem